# Adding alt/title attributes to uploaded images

Tags: entities, media

I've created a galley using fields and views thanks to this tutorial: http://jamestombs.co.uk/2011-05-26/create-album-based-image-gallery-drupal-7-using-fields-and-views

But now I can't figure how to add the usual ALT and TITLE attributes to the gallery images. The only option available is to delete the images.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are referencing states this, "On the next screen just press Save field settings."  This is where the issue starts. You have to edit the image field he tells you to create and, instead of hitting 'just save' you have to enable the options for ALT and TITLE fields, about 3/4 down the page.

Then, when you upload image, each image will display a place where you can fill these out.

Then, in views, you will have two more options - Content: Image (some_field) ALT, and Content: Image (some_field) Title. You can then select these as fields and theme them as needed to be part of your image gallery

Comment: We all had to start somewhere :) post again if I was mistaken about any of that. good luck!